# Why memory allocation of 2^80 bytes doesn't fail?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Following code doesn't throw exception and prints "success". Why ?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    size_t size = size_t(1024)*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024;
    char* data = new char[size];

    if (data == NULL)
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
- OS:       Ubuntu 12.04
- RAM: 8 GB

And if this is how it's meant to work, how do I check that I have enough memory ?

[**Edit:** made my stupid code a bit more correct, now it would at least fail on x64 if I remove two `*1024`]

Comment: Hint: Integer Overflow

Comment: Regardless of everything else, this program can never print `"fail"`, because `new` doesn't return a null pointer on failure. It throws `std::bad_alloc` instead.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes: this is not mandatory. One may override `new` and do whatever is necessary. Though this is against the standard.

Comment: @valdo this program does not override anything.

Comment: I have to say, even though my first reaction was a double-facepalm, this question gave me a good laugh. And the fact that it shows research effort means I will upvote it. The title itself is a fine example of click-bait.

Comment: @valdo: how can something be "not mandatory", if doing otherwise is "against the standard"?

Comment: Might be partially due to something like this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33514

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: yeah, I've read I have to do [`new (nothrow)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20new[]/) to get NULL. But I was quite puzzled with behavior, and didn't know what else to try.

Comment: @Mysticial: I've done about 2^80 facepalms since I've read your 1st comment and also had a good laugh. I guess, the fact that it's my 14th day as C++ developer can give me a bit of excuse, though.

Comment: Also note that 2^80 can be written as (1ul << 80), which is easier to read than multiple multiplication. It will result in overflow, though.

Comment: @divanov: forgot about this. Indeed, it looks much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My compiler can answer this one:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.7.1 20120721 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic q12507456.c++
q12507456.c++: In function 'int main()':
q12507456.c++:5:42: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
$
```

Answer (score 6):

This is more than likely to be the fact that the number you are requesting is too large to be stored within an integer and you are experiencing overflow here and the memory allocated is in fact far far less than you think it is.

Here  2^80 = 1208925819614629174706176 according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yobibyte

Comment: `the memory allocated is in fact far far less than you think it is` - just FYI, my compiler sets `size == 0`

Answer (score 5):

```
1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024*1024
```

causes an integer overflow when calculated - that is, it will be taken modulo 2^32 (or 2^64, depending on your system), and that's zero bytes which can be allocated.

Comment: Where the "much smaller amount" is zero.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that on linux `malloc` (which ultimately backs `new`) can [overcommit](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html):

> Since 2.1.27 there are a sysctl `VM_OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY` and proc file
>   /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory with values 1: do overcommit, and 0
>   (default): don't.

`malloc` will succeed and reserve the VA but not back it up with pages. When a page is accessed it may or may not succeed to committ it. [OOM Killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) may run. IF all fails, you'll get an GPF on access.

Opinions are divided whether this behavior is crazy (sane people are on this camp) or brilliant (crazy people are on that camp).

Comment: `how do I check that I have enough memory?` -> not by allocating, because of the overcommit issue.

Comment: I'd still get rid of the "Because..." - the reason this is failing is not overcommit, it's an integer overflow.

Comment: @themel: fair enough. on my g++ (4.1.2 running on x86) it won't compile with original code: `error: overflow in constant expression`.

Comment: The OOM killer is *batsh_t insane*, but usually doesn't cause problems in normal scenarios. Unfortunately since Linux has had overcommitting by default for a very long time, it can't be safely disabled because many programs aren't written to handle `malloc()` failures (I'm looking at you, Apache httpd). More discussion about this topic available [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/101916/).

Comment: @Justin: yes, the analogy there is awesome :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for information! I'm just a couple of months on Linux and have never heard of this before. I have, let's say, mixed fillings about this ... feature.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are aware of the following, but I will state it just for clarification. An exception is not being literally thrown, the code is being tested by if statements. Regardless of what terminology and methods you are using for your test, there is a more relevant observation to take note on. 
   Your system holds a maximum value for integers, and C++ will take it into consideration during compilation by doing checks and behaving some way accordingly. Once again, you may also already know that.
  My guess would be that the value either went back to 0 then up to the excessive amount or that the value that was there before the pointer started pointing to it was kept intact (Most likely). In that case, the pointer wouldn't be `NULL`. Try giving making it `NULL` upon declaration, then allocate the memory and see weather or not it passes your if statements.

Comment: "An exception is not being literally thrown" - that is the correct terminology. You expect a `std::bad_alloc` exception. The result is in fact **not** tested by the if statement.

Comment: just FYI, my compiler have set overflowed value to 0.